# How to restart an Azure appservice from Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can you restart an AppService from Azure's Powershell running in a Runbook in an Automation Account in an ARM subscription in Azure?

I thought the approach would be:

```
Restart-AzureWebsite -Name "your-appservice-name"
```

but that gets:

```
Restart-AzureWebsite : No default subscription has been designated.
Use select-AzureSubscription -Default #<subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
```

There is no Restart-AzureRmWebApp available in Azure PowerShell.

All combinations of the following lead to just a bunch of other error messages:

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'your-credentials-name'
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
Add-AzureRMAccount -Credential $Cred
Get-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName 'your-subscription-name' | Select-AzureSubscription -Default
Restart-AzureWebsite -Name "your-appservice-name"
```

Comment: `Restart-AzureWebsite` this is a classic cmdlet. What is the version of you Azure Power Shell? `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: That command doesn't even run in Azure Powershell; it returns:
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.  Common reasons that runbook jobs fail can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-troubleshooting-automation-errors

Comment: In runbook, you need import module `AzureRM.Websites`,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery

Comment: Import-Module AzureRM.Websites resulted in:
Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM.Websites' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any 
module directory.

Comment: Hi, you only need import the module to your automation accounts, then you could use the cmdlet. No need use `Import-Module AzureRm.Websites` in your runbook.

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Websites/4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no Restart-AzureRmWebApp available in Azure PowerShell.

As  **Walter - MSFT** mentioned that we could import AzureRM.Websites, before that we need to update `AzureRM.Profile` to **4.0**, more detail you could refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Before to do that we could create Azure AD service principal **locally**.
How to create service principal we could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal)

```
 Login-AzureRmAccount
 $sp = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -DisplayName exampleapp -Password "password"
 Sleep 20
 New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ApplicationId
```

Run Restart-AzureRmWebApp command in the Runbook.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -Name "WebApp Name"
```

[image]

Comment: None of those commands (Login-AzureRmAccount and Restart-AzureRmWebApp) are available from within a Runbook.

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to add a module for automation account.

Answer (score 0):

This Powershell script works inside an Azure Automation Runbook:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "<your-resource-group-name>" -ResourceName "<your-resource-name>" -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -Action 'Restart' -Force
```

**Edit**

However the next script is probably better; it relies on @Tom Sun's answer above, i.e.

1. Upgrade the modules - go to Automation Accounts / Modules / Update Azure Modules.
2. Import the AzureRm.Websites module - go to Automation Accounts / Modules / Browse Gallery.
3. Create  under Automation Accounts / Credentials.

   ```
   $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name '<your-credentials>'
   Add-AzureRMAccount -Credential $Cred

   Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName '<your-subscription-name>' | Select-AzureRmSubscription

   Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "office" -Name "<your-appservice-name>"
   ```